# Find multiple files at once via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight

I have a list of filnames like this:

```
P1020804.JPG
P1020805.JPG
P1020806.JPG
P1020807.JPG
P1020808.JPG
```

How to best find them all by single query in Spotlight, Terminal, mdfind or locate?

Comment: Are they all in the same directory (folder)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume your *list* is just a representative list and the *filenames* follow that *pattern* and may actually be more then those exact filenames. So, the use of an *extended regular expression* is going to be used to *find* the files matching the *pattern* shown in the example filenames in your OP.

```
find -E . -regex '.*\/P[0-9]{7}\.JPG'
```

- `-E` Interpret regular expressions followed by `-regex` and `-iregex` primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE’s). The `re_format(7)` manual page fully describes both formats.
- `.` Searches the current directory and its subdirectories.
- `-regex pattern` True if the whole path of the file matches pattern using regular expression.
- `.*\/P[0-9]{7}\.JPG`

  - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators).
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
  - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive).
  - P matches the character `P` literally (case sensitive).
  - `[0-9]` match a single character present in the list.
  - `{7}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 7 times, `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` (index 48) and `9` (index 57) (case sensitive).
  - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive).
  - JPG matches the characters `JPG` literally (case sensitive).

---

```
$ find -E . -regex '.*\/P[0-9]{7}\.JPG'
./Pictures/P1020799.JPG
./Pictures/P1020800.JPG
./Pictures/P1020801.JPG
./Pictures/P1020802.JPG
./Pictures/P1020803.JPG
./Pictures/P1020804.JPG
./Pictures/P1020805.JPG
./Pictures/P1020806.JPG
./Pictures/P1020807.JPG
./Pictures/P1020808.JPG
./Pictures/P1020809.JPG
./Pictures/P1020810.JPG
$
```

Note: The `.` is the current working directory, which by default if you just opened Terminal will be your Home directory. If the files are elsewhere you can use a different starting path, e.g. `/` will start in the *root* of the Macintosh HD, (assuming default naming).  As you can see in the example output the target filenames found by the *regex pattern* were in my Pictures folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name 'P1020804.JPG' -o -name 'P1020805.JPG' -o -name 'P1020806.JPG'
```

Remember that `.` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . \( -name P1020804.JPG -o \
          -name P1020805.JPG -o \
          -name P1020806.JPG -o \
          -name P1020807.JPG -o \
          -name P1020808.JPG \)
```

`find` in the current directory- `.` and sub-directories, the file name or the next file name... and so on.